# Ansible looping over with_items $n times

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to write an ansible script that configures the same id on multiple collections on multiple dbs all on the same mongo server. How do I go about running with_items $n number of times?

The collections are known and the MongoDbs have the same name configured

I tried initially a few approaches with with_items. I think I should be able to use with_nested but it doesn't seem to be liking how I formatted my $n into a list.

```
- set_fact:
    mongo_list: "{{range(1, {{ number_devsims }} + 1) | list}}"

- name: Updating simid
  command: "mongo \"{{ mongo_db_name }}-{{ item[1] }}\" --eval 'db.{{ item[0] }}.update({}, {$set : {simid : \"{{ devsim_eng_simid }}\"}})'"
  with_nested:
    - ['engines', 'servers', 'simulations']
    - "{{ mongo_list}}"
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to update all collections for each mongo. So for example

```
- set_fact:
    mongo_list: [1, 2]
```

```
TASK [devsim_data : Updating simid] *********************************************************************************
Wednesday 21 August 2019  10:42:51 -0700 (0:00:07.602)       0:00:37.450 ****** 
 [WARNING]: The loop variable 'item' is already in use. You should set the `loop_var` value in the `loop_control`
option for the task to something else to avoid variable collisions and unexpected behavior.

changed: [eco] => (item=['engines', 1])
changed: [eco] => (item=['engines', 2])
changed: [eco] => (item=['servers', 1])
changed: [eco] => (item=['servers', 2])
changed: [eco] => (item=['simulations', 1])
changed: [eco] => (item=['simulations', 2])
```

The error I seem to be getting with my set_fact is

```
TASK [devsim_data : set_fact] ***************************************************************************************
Wednesday 21 August 2019  10:50:40 -0700 (0:00:00.066)       0:00:17.668 ****** 
fatal: [eco]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: {{range(1, {{ number_devsims }} + 1) | list}}"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to nest `{{` markers inside another Jinja expression:

```
    mongo_list: "{{range(1, {{ number_devsims }} + 1) | list}}"
```

Since you're already inside a Jinja context, the nested `{{...}}` is unnecessary; this should just be:

```
    mongo_list: "{{range(1, number_devsims + 1) | list}}"
```

With that fix, I think everything else should pretty much work. I wrapped your `command` task in a `debug` task to test it, like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    number_devsims: 2
    mongo_db_name: example
    devsim_eng_simid: example-eng-simid
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        mongo_list: "{{range(1, number_devsims + 1) | list}}"

    - name: Updating simid
      debug:
        msg:
          command: "mongo \"{{ mongo_db_name }}-{{ item[1] }}\" --eval 'db.{{ item[0] }}.update({}, {$set : {simid : \"{{ devsim_eng_simid }}\"}})'"
      with_nested:
        - ['engines', 'servers', 'simulations']
        - "{{ mongo_list}}"
```

And this results in:

```
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Updating simid] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['engines', 1]) => {
    "msg": {
        "command": "mongo \"example-1\" --eval 'db.engines.update({}, {$set : {simid : \"example-eng-simid\"}})'"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['engines', 2]) => {
    "msg": {
        "command": "mongo \"example-2\" --eval 'db.engines.update({}, {$set : {simid : \"example-eng-simid\"}})'"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['servers', 1]) => {
    "msg": {
        "command": "mongo \"example-1\" --eval 'db.servers.update({}, {$set : {simid : \"example-eng-simid\"}})'"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['servers', 2]) => {
    "msg": {
        "command": "mongo \"example-2\" --eval 'db.servers.update({}, {$set : {simid : \"example-eng-simid\"}})'"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['simulations', 1]) => {
    "msg": {
        "command": "mongo \"example-1\" --eval 'db.simulations.update({}, {$set : {simid : \"example-eng-simid\"}})'"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['simulations', 2]) => {
    "msg": {
        "command": "mongo \"example-2\" --eval 'db.simulations.update({}, {$set : {simid : \"example-eng-simid\"}})'"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```